# GLM unprojects returns wrong results

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

In my project I use a fairly complex camera glass which doues trackball / arcball rotation arround the center. That works fine sofar. For the creation of the MVP matrix I use:

```
// Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVP");

// Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 <-> 100 units
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 50.f);
// Camera matrix
glm::mat4 view = camera->getMatrix();
// Model matrix -> identity matrix (origin)
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

// our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
glm::mat4 MVP = projection * view * model;
```

VertexShader is also not surprising (just showing a part here) `v_position = MVP * vec4(vPos,1);`  and works well so far.

To get the normalized direction that the mouse is pointing at I use the following code:
  `direction = glm::normalize( glm::unProject(glm::vec3(mouseX,700 - mouseY, 1), model, projection, glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 700, 700)));` - wehere 700 is the width and height of the screen.

At some other point I try to do intersections tests using the glm intersectRayTriangle function:
`glm::intersectRayTriangle(cameraPosition, direction , v0, v1, v2, intersectionPos, dist)`
And here is the problem: I don't get right results, so I guess somewhere in the unProject code a error is existing. Maybe someone has an idea about that.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the view ray for each pixel will depend on the `view` matrix, but here:

> ```
> direction = glm::normalize( glm::unProject(glm::vec3(mouseX,700 - mouseY, 1), model, projection, glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 700, 700)));
> ```

you are not taking the `view` matrix into account at all.

You need to use `view * model` as the `model` parameter. Or maybe just `view` if you want the world space coordinates.

The parameter names for the `glm::unProject` function are actually misleading here. Let me qutoe the [glm the reference pages](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html#ga82a558de3ce42cbeed0f6ec292a4e1b3):

> ```
> GLM_FUNC_DECL tvec3<T, P> glm::unProject  (   tvec3< T, P > const &   win,
>                                               tmat4x4< T, P > const & model,
>                                               tmat4x4< T, P > const & proj,
>                                               tvec4< U, P > const & viewport)
> ```

With the following description (emphasis mine):

> `model` Specifies the **modelview** matrix

As glm tries to mimic the old legacy GL functions, and fixed function pipeline in GL always used to keep the total transform in the decomposited form as `ModelView` and `Projection` matrices, this is understandable for anyone knowing the old `gluUnproject` function...